# SQL Server : convert column by different condition in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, charindex

I have a table that contains a string address. I want to select the column text in a specific format. However, the column contains a different format and it requires different rules. For example, if the column contains words like 'SHOP', it will select the wording **start** with 'SHOP'.
If the column contains words like 'BOX', it will select the wording **after** 'BOX'.

Table A

```
| columna | address          |
+---------+------------------+
| a1234   | ddsa SHOP LG123  |
| 4322    | SADA BOX 12-42   |
| 4632    | 123123 ADV  2313 |
```

I want something like this: select by the different conditions in different rules in the same column.

```
SELECT 
    ta.columna,
    if CHARINDEX('SHOP',ta.address) > 0
        RIGHT(ta.address, len(ta.address) - charindex('SHOP', ta.address)+1) AS unit_addr,
    if CHARINDEX('BOX',ta.address) > 0
        RIGHT(ta.address, len(ta.address) - charindex('BOX', ta.address)-8) AS unit_addr,
    if CHARINDEX('ADV',ta.address) > 0
        RIGHT(ta.address, charindex('ADV', ta.address)-3) AS unit_addr
FROM 
    tableA ta
```

So the output should be this:

```
| columna | address        |
+---------+----------------+
| a1234   | SHOP LG123     |
| 4322    | 12-42          |
| 4632    | 2313           |
```

Comment: Providing DDL+DML makes it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: You can't use `IF` within a query, you use `CASE` for that.

Comment: Not with the sample data provided it doesn't - "LIGHTBOX" <> "SADA BOX" :) and you have leading blanks in the last line with that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a Case expression. Assuming the logic above does what you need, this sort of thing should provide the result in the structure you want...

```
select ta.columna,
       case 
           when CHARINDEX('SHOP',ta.address) > 0 then
               RIGHT(ta.address, len(ta.address) - charindex('SHOP', ta.address)+1)
           when CHARINDEX('LIGHTBOX',ta.address) > 0 then
               RIGHT(ta.address, len(ta.address) - charindex('LIGHTBOX', ta.address)-8)
           when CHARINDEX('ADV',ta.address) > 0 then
               RIGHT(ta.address, charindex('ADV', ta.address)-3)
       end as address
from tablea ta
```